# What was Prince Philip’s surname (prior to Mountbatten)?

Tags: world-war-two, royalty, surname

[Prince Philip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince_Philip,_Duke_of_Edinburgh) took the surname of Mountbatten when he became a naturalised British citizen in 1947. His name prior to that was Schleswig Holstein Sonderburg Gluckburg. Did he use the full name while serving in the Navy prior to 1947? It seems a mouthful to use while on operational duties and could also presumably have caused some issues, by highlighting the German elements of his background.

Edited to clarify I am asking about naval service prior to 1947.

Comment: He was [Lieutenant Mountbatten](https://www.businessinsider.com/prince-philip-helped-sink-enemy-ships-during-world-war-ii-2021-4) See caption of photo.  He used that name from his [Cadet days](https://www.republicworld.com/world-news/uk-news/prince-philips-naval-career-from-best-cadet-to-world-war-2-service-a-look-back.html).

Comment: Why is [his Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince_Philip,_Duke_of_Edinburgh) insufficient?

Comment: These references all show 1947, when he took the name Mountbatten. I’m asking about the name he used prior to that.

Comment: 1) Your question specifically asks what name he used while serving in the Navy; please clarify the question.  Why does a prince need a last name?  Not all people/cultures use surnames.  I suspect that "Of Denmark & Greece" would have sufficed.

Comment: While attending the Elms, American school, in Paris in the 1920s he was teased by the other students for not having a second name. When required, the school referred to him as Philip of Greece.

Comment: Edited to make it clearer I’m asking about naval service before the name change (which includes wartime service).

Comment: Harry was called "Captain Wales" in the Army. Princes don't need surnames, but I guess the systems demanded something.

Comment: German ???  Nothing specific german in that name.  But Danish yes !

Comment: Glücksburg is the royal house of Denmark.

Comment: @Stefan Skoglund   The House of  Schleswig Holstein Sonderburg Glucksburg is a branch of the House of Oldenburg,  Oldenburg is in Germany, Schleswig was in Denmark but is now divided between Denmark and Germany.  Holstein is in Germany,  Sonderburg is right at the Danish side of the border with Germany, and Glucksburg is right at the German side of the border with Denmark  So the name is a partially German name.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace They don't. When his son Prince Charles was an undergrad at Cambridge University, he was identified on examination lists etc as "Wales, H.R.H." in the same style as "Wallace, M.C."

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Prior to the adoption of Mountbatten in February 1947, Prince Philip did not use a surname. In the navy during World War II, he was known as [HRH Prince Philip](https://www.forces-war-records.co.uk/records/24956153/acting-sub-lieutenant-his-royal-highness-prince-philip-royal-navy-royal-navy/). Thus, while serving as First Lieutenant on [HMS Wallace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMS_Wallace_(1918)) (Oct. 1942 to Jan. 1944), he was **Lt HRH Prince Philip, RN.** He was also referred to as **Sub-Lieutenant Prince Philip of Greece** in the 12th of August, 1942 edition of the [Dundee Evening Telegraph](https://www.britishnewspaperarchive.co.uk/search/results/1941-01-01/1945-12-31?basicsearch=first%2Blieutenant%2Bprince%2Bphilip&exactsearch=false&retrievecountrycounts=false&sortorder=score).

Nonetheless, some sources misleadingly refer to him as Philip Mountbatten while he was serving on various ships during World War II, despite the well-established fact that this name was not adopted until 2 years after the war had ended.

The non-use of a surname dated back to his childhood. At the age of six, he was sent to a "a progressive American kindergarten" in Paris called Elms, where

> Asked to introduce himself in class he insisted at first that he was
> ‘just **Philip**’, before eventually awkwardly admitting that he was
> ‘**Philip of Greece**’.

*Source: Philip Eade, ['Young Prince Philip: His Turbulent Early Life'](https://archive.org/details/youngprincephili0000eade) (2011)*

Later, at Salem’s junior school, Spetzgart,

> Philip was known by his first name by the English and American boys,
> whereas the Germans addressed him simply as ‘Greece’.

*Source: Eade*

while at his next school, [Gordonstoun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gordonstoun), he

> was **listed simply by his Christian name on the school register**

*Source: Eade*

In his private life, he was also known simply as 'Philip' or 'Philip of Greece' (according to the Canadian debutante [Osla Benning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osla_Benning), with whom Philip was romantically linked).

On the adoption of the name 'Mountbatten',

> Philip might have been expected to take his paternal dynastic name of
> Schleswig-Holstein-Sonderburg-Glücksburg. This, though, would have
> looked incongruous on a British passport, and by drawing attention to
> his German ancestry with the trials at Nuremberg only recently
> concluded it would have been distinctly unhelpful to his cause.
> Genealogists at the College of Arms had come up with the snappier
> alternative of Oldcastle, an anglicized version of Oldenburg, the
> German duchy where the royal house of Greece and Denmark had
> originated, but this did not find favour either; as much as anything
> because it was thought to sound slightly plebeian.

Eventually, the name Mountbatten was settled on, this being the anglicized version of his mother's name. Even so,

> Philip, meanwhile, by his own account, ‘wasn’t madly in favour [of
> taking the name Mountbatten] … but in the end I was persuaded, and
> anyway I couldn’t think of a reasonable alternative’.

*Source: Eade*

Comment: Thank you for such a full answer.

Comment: What 'he used' may not be what he *had* for a name. Any passports for him in the early days? deWP says it was "of Greece *and Denmark"*. What seems quite awkward is that Germans in Spetzgart were using 'Griechenland' as form of address? That seems so long and complicated for use between little boys, I have trouble just buying that.

Comment: @LаngLаngС In my high school people often would refer to one another by the (small) town of origin, some of which weren't much shorter than *Griechenland*, which it's just three syllables. I don't see anything awkward about that (although in this case I assume it could have been abbreviated as *Griech* or *Griechen*).

Comment: @LаngLаngС Early passports may well be impossible to trace (short of asking the Queen  perhaps) as, according to [this article](https://passportia.org/blog/5281-hrh-prince-philip-the-duke-of-edinburgh.php), his nationality during his early years in Britain is uncertain. As for a 3-syllable name, why not? Lots of people have them, and I remember specific names being used by us kids when I was at school from age 7.

Comment: Whether passport or any other (birth?)-certificate/document, 'official' rather than 'used' (I 'use' "C", but "C" is not my real surname ;). // Personally, I simply doubt the veracity of these childhood anecdotes as presented, length and pronunciation sounding too awkward. Maybe they indeed did that.My hermeneutic heuristics are primitive here. But this kind of picturesque details in biography notes (also being not a surname but a call-/nickname?) in principle would surely benefit from robust substantiation.

Comment: It is surprising that anyone could get along either at school or in the military without a surname. that perhaps is why his grandson, Prince William, was known as "Will Wales" when at Eton and at University.

Comment: @LаngLаngС I agree that anecdotes are far from ideal when it comes to evidence, but please note that this answer does contain more than just anecdotes. :)

Comment: Oh, I do. It's just this one criticism, targeted  *within that src,* less for the whole answer ;) However, that whole would be even more complete by corroborating or contextualizing this slightly dubious bit?

Comment: @DenisNardin: Ha ha! Those suggestions are remarkably similar to various (pejorative and otherwise) nicknames by which I was known in middle and high school).

Comment: @LangLangC  From what I have heard, the German language is famous for putting short words together to make new words that are much longer and more complicated, and hard for non Germans to pronounce.  German boys old enough to be in school should thus have been routinely using long and complicated words and have no trouble using a short word like  'Griechenland'.

Comment: @MAGolding There's some exaggeration. Germans use short words, colloquially, whenever possible. I'm used to using nick names of just one syllable.